# haproxy is auto restarted every few minutes in ubuntu

Tags: haproxy

my haproxy is auto restarted every few minutes, is it by design? from syslog:

```
    Aug 23 04:24:31 localhost haproxy[64543]: [NOTICE] 235/042431 (64543) : New worker #1 (64544) forked
Aug 23 04:24:38 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Succeeded.
Aug 23 04:51:11 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 23 04:51:11 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 04:51:11 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Aug 23 04:52:17 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 23 04:52:17 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 04:52:18 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Aug 23 04:56:15 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 23 04:56:15 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 04:56:16 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Aug 23 04:56:36 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 23 04:56:36 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 04:56:36 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Aug 23 04:59:19 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 23 04:59:19 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 04:59:19 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 23 05:00:20 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 23 05:00:20 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 05:00:21 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
Aug 23 05:01:15 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 23 05:01:15 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 05:01:15 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 7.
Aug 23 05:04:15 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 23 05:04:15 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 05:04:15 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 8.
Aug 23 05:05:23 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 23 05:05:23 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 05:05:24 api-lb systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 9.
```

it's running under Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with HA-Proxy version 2.0.13-2 2020/04/01 - https://haproxy.org/, main config as:

```
    global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    maxconn 80000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # See: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&server-version=2.0.3&config=intermediate
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
    maxconn 80000
    retries 3
```

any thoughts? We just do not want to lose the stats b/c each restart will ease the stats.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried asking HAProxy to check its configuration? Do you have any logs from HAProxy itself?

Comment: Also, what does your systemd service look like?

Comment: I didn't ask haproxy. I do not find any other logs from /var/log/syslog and systemd file: https://gist.github.com/fayland/5b74c8e75e19291b8143ad14f4fab85e

Comment: Exit code 137 means you have run out of memory. Check how much memory your system has available.

Comment: but free -m shows 6G+ available. free 704M. we're using Linode.

Comment: it's gone now. it's up for 4 hours. probably a bug in linode b/c it's shared server. how to check real free memory available? we checked `free -m` and it's lots of memory available that time.